# how to use a variable as the name of a database in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my problem. I need to have the user choose a server so I can have the program connect to that server (SQL NOTE This IS In C#)
This is what I have done, but I get an Exception

```
//first I make a variable that equals to a textbox text
//take the variable and I place it where I would put your sever name
//heres my code 

string SQLC = (textBox1.Text);
con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=FORDS-PC;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Connect Timeout=15;
                          Encrypt=False;
                          TrustServerCertificate=False;
                          ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
                          MultiSubnetFailover=False");
```

here is the ERROR

> An unhandled exception of type  System.InvalidOperationException
>   occurred in System.Data.dll)

let me know if you need anything else that i need to tell you

Comment: That connection string doesn't contain any _Database=" + SQLC_

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. - and please learn that exceptions have a MESSAGE string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the database to you connection string.

SQL Server connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
User ID=UserName;Password=Password
```

Your code

```
string SQLC = textBox1.Text;

con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=FORDS-PC;Initial Catalog="+SQLC+";Integrated Security=True;Connect 
Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;
ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");`
```

Comment: is that my code fixed also is this a code that allows the user to chose the database name

Comment: You didn't ask for code to allow for a user to choose a database. Change the textbox to a combobox, and add some items to it. Yes that code will work.